# Java: Adding panel inside another at run time to fit visible area

Tags: java, swing, jung

In my application I want to show generated graph, using JUNG. It produces JPanel object as output. So, i though it would be just a matter of adding a component to panel. But the graph is drawn outside of its parent panel. Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]
 
How do I restrict the graph to be only inside the visible area?
The code I use to add graph to panel is this (the border was for me to see panel borders, though it doesnt show for some reason):

```
    Layout<Object, String> layout = new CircleLayout<Object, String> (graphProvider.getGraph());
    layout.setSize(panel.getMarketGraphPane().getPreferredSize());
    BasicVisualizationServer<Object,String> graphPanel = new BasicVisualizationServer<Object,String>(layout);
    graphPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
    graphPanel.setSize(panel.getMarketGraphPane().getPreferredSize());
    panel.getMarketGraphPane().add(graphPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.getMarketGraphPane().revalidate();
```

Comment: An alternative is to add the graph to a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: For some reason, if i use exactly same code with scrollPane as parent panel, graph wouldnt show at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use GraphZoomScrollPane to add zoom-able graph scrollpane container for VisualizationViewer object as follows:

```
GraphZoomScrollPane pane = new GraphZoomScrollPane(visualizationViewer);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
BorderLayout panelMapLayout = new BorderLayout();
panel.setLayout(panelMapLayout);
panel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: bad idea, because adding this with borderlayout doesnt worked for me

Answer (score 3):

too little informations for the actual image

1 depends

- what `Size` returns (generated graph, by using JUNG), are you set there setSize(int, int) too,
- if is graph resiziable,

2) remove

- `layout.setSize(panel.getMarketGraphPane().getPreferredSize());`

and

- `graphPanel.setSize(panel.getMarketGraphPane().getPreferredSize());`

you can't to `setSize` for Object placed to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and I think that is possible directly put (`generated graph, using JUNG. It produces JPanel object`) to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` area, try that maybe your `twice setSize` generated some mess

and then you can call only

```
panel.add(graphPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

3) another two choises (without clean-up `setSize`)

- call `pack();` to the [Top-Level Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), notice carefully with LCD/LED monitors bounds
- put that to the [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)